# Android: Setting shadow on TextView not working

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am trying to get shadow (or a glossy effect) over textview programatically:

My Layout:

```
...
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/myblackimage"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvShadowy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="Shadowy Text"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
...
```

Set it like this on click of text

```
...
 tvShadowy.setShadowLayer(30, -5, 10, Color.RED);
```

*But nothing happens...No red shadow appears.* 
Though..setting textcolor etc. works
I removed the background image of the parent linearlayout too.. but it had no effect.

Comment: try this tvShadowy.setShadowLayer((float) 3, 1, 1, Color.RED); sure as parameters as you want! I think you miss the float ?!

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Could you post more code?

Comment: Thanks Maheera> I switched to: tvShadowy.setShadowLayer(0.01f, -2,2, Color.RED); This worked. I guess if i use very large (radius) values.. the effect is not visible...